# How should CSS Resets be applied to Polymer components?

Tags: css, polymer, polymer-1.0, web-component, shadow-dom

For example here is one reset from [superfly-css Foundation](https://github.com/superfly-css/superfly-css-foundation/blob/master/src/main/css/foundation.css):

```
    /**
     * [SB] Suppress the focus outline on elements that cannot be accessed via keyboard.
     * This prevents an unwanted focus outline from appearing around elements that
     * might still respond to pointer events.
     */

    [tabindex="-1"]:focus {
      outline: none !important;
    }
```

I would want this reset to apply to all elements, regardless of whether they are in the 'shadow dom' or 'light dom'.  Is there a way to ensure that this is the case - especially when using 3rd party components?

TIA,
Ole

Answer (score 1):

You can't modify the CSS style of Shadowed third-party Web Component, for it's one of the main features of Shadow DOM:

CSS are shut off by Shadow boundaries.
The only standard [shadow-piercing combinator](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-scoping/#shadow-piercing-descendant-combinator) doesn't apply to CSS rules.

Polymer provides no perrenial solution to apply such global resets. [Custom Properties](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/start/first-element/step-5) can be applied only if the third-party provider did implement them in its web components, which in not the case in most common scenarios.

CSS Resets will be propagated automatically to Light DOMs, and you have to insert them one by one on components with Shadow DOM.

Comment: @Supersharp note the context is polymer - css resets are used to ensure that html elements have consistent rendering across browsers, thus we need it to ensure that web components render consistently across browsers.

Comment: @Supersharp - in the end it's just html, css, and javascript.  There is a way.  It may be ugly, nasty, and hackish, but there's a way.  I filed an issue Polymer to request further clarification: https://github.com/Polymer/polymer/issues/3842

Comment: @Ole the hackish way would be to change the code directly in the source, or to access the Shadow DOMs of the inserted components via Javascript and to modify style inside.

Comment: Looks like Angular 2 has a solution to this: https://toddmotto.com/emulated-native-shadow-dom-angular-2-view-encapsulation  .... Also looking at [Tera Data Components](https://teradata.github.io/covalent/#/components) as a possible alternative to at least get consistent css reset semantics.  Now if only these can do scoped dependency management like Node does, I'm home free :)

Comment: @Ole You can also access the templates of the imported components on load, and then add inside a `<style>` tag with a `@import url` rule (before they are imported or cloned).

Comment: That's sharp!  Like it.  I'm probably going to experiment with the polymer shim anyways to see if I can get scoped dependency loading working WRT NPM, so perhaps that could be a configuration option.  I was also thinking that a linter could notify devs if any of the resets might be an issue.  I updated the polymer issue with a possible implementation approach.

Comment: Reading here https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/primers/shadowdom/ is says that inheritable styles pierce the shadow dom boundary by default, so it sounds like CSS resets may simply be applied ... at least the ones that can be inherited ...

Comment: Yep, CSS properties that inherit, continue to inherit inside of shadow dom. That means they pierce its boundary. However, `outline` is not an inheritable property (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/outline).  If you want to create a common set of shared styles to be used in multiple components, see Polymer's [Shared style modules](https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/docs/devguide/styling#style-modules)